# Questions Regarding UEFI Shell - Version 2.0 Wanted

Tags: uefi, firmware

I bought a cheap laptop for myself last Christmas, just because I wanted a laptop.  A [Toshiba Satellite C55-A5310](http://www.toshiba.com/us/computers/laptops/satellite/C50/C55-A5310) on special. I'm also a big believer in OEM software for laptops, so I left Windows 8.1 on it, stuck GParted Live USB on it, split the NTFS partition on it, and stuck Ubuntu in the new partition.  That's all gone fine...

---

### Problem

I'm old school from the days of IDE drives and legacy BIOS's, but I consider my skills to be tech savvy (don't we all?). Out of shear laziness, I haven't messed with the EFI/ESP Boot Partition because the concept is new to me, and wrapping loading code in firmware seems crazy to me, but times change, so I must adapt.  Granted, I should be reading up, but I have found better ways to waste my time as of late, until now.  Issue:

1. Grub2 loads a shim file.
2. Grub2 lives happily with the Windows Loader.
3. Windows Update Updates, and kindly doesn't tell anyone that KBXXXX updates the BCD/ESP Boot Area.  Since Grub2 is a "dirty foreign object", the shim is erased when KBXXXX updates the Configuration Data.
4. Since I hate going in circles, I finally got rid of my lazies by installing the [Refind BootManager](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/index.html)

In the process of installing the Boot Manager using the [Installing from Windows directions](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/installing.html#windows), and reading further I decided to install the [UEFI Shell](http://sourceforge.net/p/tianocore/edk2/ci/master/tree/ShellBinPkg/) following the directions in the [Installing Additional Components](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/installing.html#addons) section.  After multiple attempts of:

`mountvol s: /s`
`copy C:\shellx64.efi S:\`

I discovered 2 things that are bothering me:

1. Why does `shellx64.efi` have to sit in the root of the EFI drive?  I'm a neatfreak, so I'd like to organize my drive...
2. After multiple attempts from multiple souurces, I discovered that I don't have UEFI v. 2.3+.  The UEFI Firmware link from earlier leads to v2 of the shell, which is the most current, but everytime I tried installing v2, I got an ASSERT error, as described in [this mailing list post](http://sourceforge.net/p/edk2/mailman/message/28699596/).  As such, I found [v1 over at the ArchWiki on UEFI](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface#UEFI_Shell), which now works like a charm, but:

   - How can I upgrade my UEFI to at least 2.3, so I can use v2? or
   - How can I find out what version of UEFI I have, so that I can update the shell to the closest approximation of v2 I can get, if there are any?

If this will be of help my Setup Program/BIOS Look Alike is [InsydeH2O version 3.7](http://www.insyde.com/products)

---

### Things I've Learned

On the upside, I'll never have to use clunky GUI's that I never could get working, as I now know how to edit the BCD/ESP by hand, using either Linux or Windows.  I've also learned I cannot get lazy when it comes to technical advances.

---

### Update

While this is not the answer I'm looking for, and therefore will leave the question open, I was able to get the beta version of the 2.0 shell from the [Installing rEFInd Manually Using an EFI Shell](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/installing.html#efishell), linked as [Alternate x86-64 (64-bit) shell 2 for older EFIs](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/17629062/Shell2.zip).  This is a DropBox link, so it may not last, but issuing the `ver` command yields:

> UEFI Interactive Shell v2.0
>   Copyright 2009 - 2011 Intel(r) Corporation.  All rights
>   reserved. Beta build 1.0
>   UEFI v2.31 (INSYDE Corp., 0x10000001)

I'd still like to know how to update to the official version.

*Added 6/17/2015*: Should the Dropbox Link ever rot, the beta shell can be found on the [Refind CDR Image](http://sourceforge.net/projects/refind/files/0.8.7/refind-cd-0.8.7.zip/download) in 2 Versions, a signed version and an unsigned version.  If on Linux, one can mount the image and copy/rename either version to the root of your EFI partition.  **Please note that even this method results in a beta build of v.2.0**.  I'm still leaving this question open for future suggestions, and other possibilities, such as an Answer on how to organize the EFI partition or update the beta builds...

Comment: You [build it](http://www.tianocore.org/). The libs are weird - an MS build environment is assumed for a lot of it, Rod offers GNU-based/EDK based builds of rEFInd on sourceforge, and mentions some differences in the release notes there. A side-note - a few months ago `rEFInd` quietly added iPXE functionality - I like it. Also, if you do any virt stuff, you might want to look at the [OVMF firmware](http://tianocore.sourceforge.net/wiki/How_to_run_OVMF) for your virtual machines. I really like being able to boot the kernels I keep on my esp both from within QEMU or from a system restart.

Comment: You got the weird link, right? [Just in case](http://www.win-raid.com/t154f16-Tool-Guide-News-quot-UEFI-BIOS-Updater-quot-UBU.html).

Comment: @mikeserv I did, added it to my bookmarks

Comment: excellent. so you'll get just as much use of it as I did then.